# Android Canvas Bitmap, the image i Save is black

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

Sorry for my bad english,if you do not understand something tell me that I try to explain it better
Hello, i'm doing a test, i want first draw using canvas and a surfaceview a line, then i want to save it on my smartphone... i try this code but it saves only black image..Do you know why?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.salvaaa);


        SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        surface.getHolder().addCallback(new Callback() {

            private Context context;

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                   canvas.drawLine(20,20,30,30, paint);
                   holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                   canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);


                     Context context = getBaseContext();
                   this.context=context;
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    OutputStream fOut=null;
                    File file = new File(path, "immasine.jpg");

                    try {
                        fOut= new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                        fOut.flush();
                        fOut.close();
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }




            }

          @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            } });
    }
```

EDIT------------

I've change the code, now it works

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.salvaaa);
          Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
              canvas.drawLine(20,20,30,30, paint);
              OutputStream fOut=null;
                File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "isne");

                try {
                    fOut= new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
                   // holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: one thing I see is that You are saving it as jpg, but the compress format is png: Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG

Comment: "immasine.jpg" is the name, so it doesn't change... however I have tried to change it but nothing changes

Comment: so, You have changed Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG to Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG ?

Comment: Yes, now I have noticed that even I put ".png" it saves image in jpeg format...

Comment: sure it does, because the name is "immasine.jpg", but compressformat is PNG. But what is irritating me is: holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); - at the API there is written: "After this call, the surface's current pixels will be shown on the screen, but its content is lost, in particular there is no guarantee that the content of the Surface will remain" ....could You try it without this call? Whats the result?

Comment: If i delete it, it shows me a black screen and save black image... hovewer "imasine.jpg" is only the name, i try to change it in png or something different but is the same...